# " Is " operator returns a value different than expected

Tags: vb.net, operator-keyword

MSDN says:
"The Is operator determines if two object references refer to the same object. However, it does not perform value comparisons. If object1 and object2 both refer to the exact same object instance, result is True; if they do not, result is False."

So why this code return True or False depending on is changed the secondPerson.FirstName property?

```
 Public Class Person
    Implements Global.System.ICloneable
    Property FirstName As String
    Property LastName As String
    Public Function Clone() As Object Implements Global.System.ICloneable.Clone
        Return Me.MemberwiseClone
    End Function
End Class

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim firstPerson As New Person
        firstPerson.FirstName = "Alessandro"
        firstPerson.LastName = "Del Sole"
        Dim secondPerson As Person = CType(firstPerson.Clone, Person)
        Console.WriteLine(firstPerson.FirstName Is secondPerson.FirstName)'return True
        secondPerson.FirstName = "SomeValue"
        Console.WriteLine(firstPerson.FirstName Is secondPerson.FirstName)'return False
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: `firstPerson.FirstName` and `secondPerson.FirstName` both refer to the same string, since strings are interned.  That is why the first `Is` comparison returns True.  `MemberwiseClone` does not duplicate the string.  If you need to compare the _values_ of the string, use the `==` operator.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway There is no `==` operator in VB.NET.

Comment: @AndrewMorton - Of course I meant the equality operator.  Had my C# hat on!